# PyTorch - applying attention efficiently

Tags: python, neural-network, deep-learning, vectorization, pytorch

I have build a RNN language model with attention and I am creating context vector for every element of the input by attending all the previous hidden states *(only one direction)*.

The most straight forward solution in my opinion is using a *for-loop* over the RNN output, such that each context vector is computed one after another.

```
import torch
import torch.nn as nn
import torch.nn.functional as F

class RNN_LM(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self, hidden_size, vocab_size, embedding_dim=None, droprate=0.5):
        super().__init__()
        if not embedding_dim:
            embedding_dim = hidden_size
        self.embedding_matrix = nn.Embedding(vocab_size, embedding_dim)

        self.lstm = nn.LSTM(input_size=embedding_dim, hidden_size=hidden_size, batch_first=False)
        self.attn = nn.Linear(hidden_size, hidden_size)
        self.vocab_dist = nn.Linear(hidden_size, vocab_size)
        self.dropout = nn.Dropout(droprate)

    def forward(self, x):
        x = self.dropout(self.embedding_matrix(x.view(-1, 1)))
        x, states = self.lstm(x)
        #print(x.size())
        x = x.squeeze()
        content_vectors = [x[0].view(1, -1)]
        # for-loop over hidden states and attention
        for i in range(1, x.size(0)):
            prev_states = x[:i]
            current_state = x[i].view(1, -1)

            attn_prod = torch.mm(self.attn(current_state), prev_states.t())
            attn_weights = F.softmax(attn_prod, dim=1)
            context = torch.mm(attn_weights, prev_states)
            content_vectors.append(context)

        return self.vocab_dist(self.dropout(torch.cat(content_vectors)))
```

*Note: The `forward` method here is only used for training.*

However this solution is not very efficient as the code is not well parallelizable with computing each context vector sequently. But since the context vectors are not dependent on each other, I wonder if there is a non-sequential way of calculating them.

**So is there is a way to compute the context vectors without *for-loop* so that more of computation can be parallelized?**

Comment: I cannot really see a way to get it done without paying a 2x complexity penalty. At each step you're doing an increasingly big matmul (of complexity starting from s^2 for `i==1` up to s^3 `for i==s-1` where `s==x.size(0)`) . So to enclose this in fully vectorized operations, you would need to unify the size of matmuls, which in practice means upscaling all of them to be the same size, which is the bigger of the two and pad the unwanted space with 0s. It's unlikely to be worth it. That being said, I'd try to wrap this in a `torch.jit.script_module` and see what the jit automagic can do.

Comment: @Jatentaki Thank you for your comment. But I'm pretty sure that even with twice the complexity it would be still faster or even *much* faster if computation could be parallelized, because right now it just runs really slow on GPU. Complexity is not that important since I do not fully utilize the GPU right now, it runs only on partial load.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ok, for clarity: I assume we only really care about vectorizing the `for` loop. What is the shape of `x`? Assuming `x` is 2-dimensional, I have the following code, where `v1` executes your loop and `v2` is a vectorized version:

```
import torch
import torch.nn.functional as F

torch.manual_seed(0)

x = torch.randn(3, 6)

def v1():
    for i in range(1, x.size(0)):
        prev = x[:i]
        curr = x[i].view(1, -1)

        prod = torch.mm(curr, prev.t())
        attn = prod # same shape
        context = torch.mm(attn, prev)
        print(context)

def v2():
    # we're going to unroll the loop by vectorizing over the new,
    # 0-th dimension of `x`. We repeat it as many times as there
    # are iterations in the for loop
    repeated = x.unsqueeze(0).repeat(x.size(0), 1, 1)

    # we're looking to build a `prevs` tensor such that
    # prevs[i, x, y] == prev[x, y] at i-th iteration of the loop in v1,
    # up to 0-padding necessary to make them all the same size.
    # We need to build a higher-dimensional equivalent of torch.triu
    xs = torch.arange(x.size(0)).reshape(1, -1, 1)
    zs = torch.arange(x.size(0)).reshape(-1, 1, 1)
    prevs = torch.where(zs < xs, torch.tensor(0.), repeated)

    # this is an equivalent of the above iteration starting at 1
    prevs = prevs[:-1]
    currs = x[1:]

    # a batched matrix multiplication
    prod = torch.matmul(currs, prevs.transpose(1, 2))
    attn = prod # same shape
    context = torch.matmul(attn, prevs)
    # equivalent of a higher dimensional torch.diagonal
    contexts = torch.einsum('iij->ij', (context))
    print(contexts)

print(x)

print('\n------ v1 -------\n')
v1()
print('\n------ v2 -------\n')
v2()
```

which vectorizes your loop, with some caveats. First, I assume `x` is 2-dimensional. Secondly, I skip taking the `softmax` claiming it doesn't change the size of the input and thus doesn't affect vectorization. That's a true, but unfortunately softmax of a 0-padded vector `v` is not equal to a 0-padded softmax of unpadded `v`. This can be fixed with renormalization though. Please let me know if my assumptions are correct and whether this is a good enough starting point for your work.

Comment: Thank your, this is really great work! Your assumptions where correct, sorry that I forgot to write the shape of `x` in the question. From first tests it seems, it *can* be much faster depending on the input size and dimensions. Btw. I replaced the padded zeros by `-inf` before applying the softmax - this makes the softmax result equal to a non-padded vector :)
Once again thank you for your effort!